# MS SQL Server 2005 Copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hey all, I am trying to find out how to copy data from one table to another database table. I have two connections to two different databases. Ones called comp-DEV1 and the other SQLTEST. I am currently unable to copy data from my sorce table (SQLTEST) to my destination table (comp-DEV1).

This is the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Query:

```
 INSERT INTO comp-DEV1.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL
 SELECT *
 FROM SQLTEST.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
             FROM comp-DEV1.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL 
             WHERE (SQLTEST.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL.CID = comp-DEV1.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL.CID)
             )
```

Any help would be great :o)

David

Comment: Is `comp-DEV1` a linked server on `SQLTEST`?

Comment: Dont think it is. How do i go about linking them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your database names in brackets, such as:

```
INSERT INTO [comp-DEV1].EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL 
 SELECT * 
 FROM SQLTEST.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *  
             FROM [comp-DEV1].EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL  
             WHERE (SQLTEST.EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL.CID = 
                [comp-DEV1].EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL.CID) 
             )
```

Comment: Ok, did that and i now have a new error: Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 2
Could not find server 'SQLTEST' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: @StealthRT: You should only need to use the four name notation to access the Linked Server instance - you can omit it when referencing tables on the current instance: `SELECT * FROM EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL WHERE ...`

Comment: @OMG Ponies (haha). You are correct but i still get the error since, im guessing, the databases are not linked together?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following statement first to check that you can read the source from the destination server:

SELECT *
FROM [comp-DEV1].EMSSQL.dbo.tblCL

Get that working first then you should be on your way...